# Using Math Functions in an IF statement

Tags: javascript

Hi I've just started to learn JavaScript. I'm doing the exercises on http://www.codecademy.com/. You can read it below:

FizzBuzz is a children's game where you count from 1 to 20. Easy, right?

Here's the catch: instead of saying numbers divisible by 3, say "Fizz". And instead of saying numbers divisible by 5, say "Buzz". For numbers divisible by both 3 and 5, say "FizzBuzz".

"1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz"...and so forth

Let's start by using console.log to print out all of the numbers from 1 and 20.

But don't type out the numbers in order—find a more awesome way!

I can get the numbers to print using a for loop but now I don't know how to replace the numbers with strings.

I thought about doing an IF statement like "if i divided by 3 is zero, then print Fizz" but I'm not sure how to do it. See what I've done so far below:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i <=20; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
if (i / 3 = 0) {
    console.log("Fizz")
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Unless i is 0, i/3 cannot be 0.

Answer (score 3):

You need to test the remainder with the modulus operator.

```
if (i % 3 === 0) {
```

The modulus operator returns the remainder after dividing the left operand by the right.

```
12 % 3;  // 0
13 % 3;  // 1
14 % 3;  // 2
15 % 3;  // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Comparisons are done with the `==` (or `===`) operator, not `=`.  The latter is for assignments of values to variables or object properties.

To do your `if` statement, then, you'd write this:

```
if (i / 3 === 0) {
   // ...
}
```

I used `===` because it's *usually* the right thing; `==` has some weird semantics that can be really confusing before you've gotten the hang of JavaScript.

As @kennebec notes in a comment, you may want to think through your logic again. Perhaps you want to check whether the number is *divisible* by three.  In that case, you'd want to use the modulus operator:

```
if (i % 3 === 0) {
  // i is divisible by 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var i;
for(i=1; i<=20; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if(i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");    
    }
    else if(i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }
}
```

Using the modulus operator will allow you to check if i is divisable with 3 or 5, as i/3 will only be 0 when i is 0.
Hope this will help you proceed to your practice in javascript

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
for (i=1; i<21; i++) {

    if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 !== 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } 

    else if (i%5 === 0 && i%3 !== 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }

    else if (i%5 === 0 && !i%3 === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }
    else {
       console.log(i); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you're going to want something more like `(i % 3 == 0)`.

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript so it might be a different operator, if that's the case, `%` means *modulus*. It returns the remainder of dividing to numbers. So in your case, let's say `i` is `3`. Then `i / 3 == 1`, but `i % 3 == 0`. If `i` was `6`, `i / 3 == 2`, but `i % 3 == 0` still.